# Can't run meteor app in windows 8.1 with tasklist error

Tags: meteor

After installed meteor 1.1.0.2 locally in my windows 8.1, I follow the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try) to run my first app. But when I try to run it, here came the following:

```
D:\git\SPI-hw\SPI\lab8\simple-todos>meteor run
[[[[[ ~\D\git\SPI-hw\SPI\lab8\simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.

C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\
dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                            throw(ex);
                                                  ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: {"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null}
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\
1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\
packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:120:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\
packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:236:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\
packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:360:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\
mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:612:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\
packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:712:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\
packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:670:10)
    at C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\
1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-all.js:199:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\Users\pyjx\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\
1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:73:24
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:662:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

I have googled the problem and there do some answers in the meteor's issues, like this [Win XP Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe (when meteor run)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4128). But it made no sense, and my tasklist command is in my path. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and likewise tasklist is in my path if I enter the dos command 'where tasklist' I get a correct answer
nearly all the other answers online say to fix the tasklist but don't think this is helping in my case

Answer (score 0):

In my case, tasklist could only be run as Administrator